# Change Eclipse variable autohighlight color

Tags: eclipse

I have customized my own colors in eclipse but cannot find where to change the auto highlight color when you click on a variable and it highlights all other uses.  Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`Preferences` -> `General` -> `Editors` -> `Text Editors` -> `Annotations` -> `Occurrences`

Comment: By the way, "Occurrences" defines the color and shape of a highlighted variable's **use inside expressions**. If you want to change the color and shape of that variable when used as an **assignment target**, then change "Write Occurrences".

Comment: For js files there is a separate menu item for 'JavaScript Occurrences'

Comment: Thanks, I checked that, it is set correctly, but still occurences are not "highlighted". What other color param may "cancel" or override this rule ? Any idea ? I hava a LiClipse plugin installed.

Answer (score 0):

##### How to change your various variable background-highlighting "occurrences" settings

For anyone who'd like a screenshot and more details:

*Tested in Eclipse 2022-12 (4.26.0) on Ubuntu 22.04.*

You may have various "Occurrences" settings to change. Each one causes variables of the same name from various language file types to be highlighted in different kinds of files. I have 5 or so "occurrences" settings in `Window` → `Preferences` → `General` → `Editors` → `Text Editors` → `Annotations` → in the “Annotation types” window:

1. Bash occurrences
2. C/C++ Occurrences
3. C/C++ Write Occurrences
4. Occurrences
5. Occurrences (LiClipse)

I have changed all 5 to the same custom color: `#414104`, which is a nice-looking brown which looks great for dark themes.

Here's a screenshot *prior to* changing that setting for "Occurrences (LiClipse)":

[image]

And here's the new color I set all 5 to: `#414104`:

[image]

##### References:

1. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1126826/4561887)
2. I first wrote about this in my [Eclipse setup instructions on a new Linux (or other OS) computer](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LbuxOsDHfpMksGdpX5X-7l7o_TIIVFPkH2eD23cXUmA/edit?usp=sharing) document, where I have documented this and a lot more.