# How to change the background color of a potential match in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, color-scheme

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change Eclipse variable autohighlight color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126802/change-eclipse-variable-autohighlight-color)

I am trying to customize Eclipse for a color scheme better for my eyes. I have a couple of questions

1. Is there a way to save all the changes that I have made so far under my own "theme"?
2. I have done all the changes that I want except one: when I select a word in my code, eclipse will highlight all the occurrences of that word. It does so by putting the background yellow. The problem is that with my color schemes this doesn't allow me to see what is actually there. I have attached a picture so that you can see what I am talking about.

I am using Pydev in an iMac. Any suggestions about this or how to reduce eye strain will be much appreciated.

[image: screenshot of my eclipse]

Comment: Good question, but it *may* be better on Super user.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the other answer: window > preferences > general > editors > text editors > annotations > occurrences.

As for the other part of the answer, yes, you should be able to export/import Eclipse preferences to configure your theme. See: http://pydev.blogspot.com.br/2009/07/creating-dark-theme-and-exporting-and.html for details on that.

But instead of going that route, I'd suggest one of the following:

1. Use Aptana Studio 3 which has a theming concept built-in (see: http://pydev.org/download.html for details on getting it)
2. Use the Eclipse Color Themes plugin: http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/ (which will apply a given theme to multiple editors at once)

Comment: +1 for the path to JavaScript Occurrences. However, I have found that none of the Eclipse Color Themes are really any better than the basic Dark Mode. IMO Eclipse just does not handle dark mode well. I only use it because I find a white background painful to look at all day.